# Что и почему в этой программе будет на выводе?

Tags: c

Скомпилировав и запустив я получил ответ на вопрос "Что будет на выводе" - 4 6 6 5 4 5.

Я понимаю почему первые 5 числа именно такие, однако не понимаю и не могу объяснить, почему после использовании функции `test(&b)`, переменная b равняется уже 5. Если не сложно, прошу подробно объяснить работу этой программы.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 4, b = 5;

void test(int *c)
{
    int a = *c; printf( "%d %d\n", a, b ); // a = 6; b = 5;

    if (a > b) 
    { 
        a = b; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        int b = a; 
        printf( "%d\n %d\n", a, b ); 
    }

    *c = a;
}

int main (void)
{
    int b = 6; printf( "%d %d\n", a, b ); // a = 4; b = 6;
    test(&b);  printf( "%d %d\n", a, b ); // 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: За что минусуете вопрос? :(

Comment: Я наоборот указал Ваш ответ верный и нажал на плюс.

Comment: Не, я не к тебе обращался. Я именно про рейтинг вопроса +2 -2. А у ответа +5 -0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что в `test` нет `b` - та `b`, которая была в `main`е в `test` известна как `*c`. 
Соответственно, при выводе `b` берётся глобальная, которая написана строчкой выше.

> в main переменная b равняется уже тому, что было в функции test?

Переменная `b` из `main` и "переменная" `*c` из `test` - это одно и то же.
Когда в `test` выполняется `*c = a;` её значение перезаписывается.

Comment: Это я понял, не понимаю только одного, после вызова функции test, в main переменная b равняется уже тому, что было в функции test?

Comment: @Danya, ответ дополнен.

Comment: @Danya В функцию test передается не сама переменная `b`, а адрес в памяти, где она расположена. `test` принимает указатель на функцию и `*c=a;` кладет содержимое переменной `a` по адресу, указанному в `c`, т.е. в переменную `b` `main`